# Как использовать glibc

Tags: ubuntu, glib

Для одного из проектов необходим GLIBC_2.29
ос ubuntu-18.04.

```
OSError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by..
```

Пробовал по инструкци https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72513993/how-to-install-glibc-2-29-or-higher-in-ubuntu-18-04.
Установка не проходит, или проходит, но не до конца.

```
touch /home/user/glibc-2.29_build/manual/stamp-pkgvers
touch: cannot touch '/home/user/glibc-2.29_build/manual/stamp-pkgvers': Permission denied
Makefile:113: recipe for target '/home/user/glibc-2.29_build/manual/stamp-pkgvers' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/user/glibc-2.29_build/manual/stamp-pkgvers] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/glibc-2.29/manual'
Makefile:258: recipe for target 'manual/subdir_install' failed
make[1]: *** [manual/subdir_install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/glibc-2.29'
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Как установить сие?

Comment: Обновить убунту, или в докере запустить более новую? Или утащить из более новой сбилженную библиотеку, но не уверен, насколько это легко. И ошибки сборки покажите.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, добавил в вопрос ошибку

Comment: `Permission denied` - смотрели какие права на папке?